# Unknown Notification Alerts

Tags: notifications

My S3 constantly sounds a Notification alert but I can't tell what it is trying to notify me about.  No new emails, no new messages.  What is it trying to tell me?

Comment: I take it you don't have a repeat notification app installed?

Comment: That would be correct - not sure what that is but I'll investigate.  Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate question of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26371/7574